# Android Clipboard data to be stored in application memory?

Tags: android, clipboard, clipboarddata

I need to store data copied from an app into another app's memory than letting Android store it in global clipboard.

Is it possible to copy the data into a separate memory than the global clipboard.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Nibs

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ClipBoardManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/ClipboardManager.html) class to get clipboard data, and save it (to a file perhaps?) which the other app can access. See [Copy and Paste](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste.html) for an example.

Comment: yes @umair, its obvious that i would be using ClipboardManager, but how would i avoid lettting it store in the global clipboard and how would i be saving it in another apps memory ?

Comment: If you save the data copied from the clipboard with a timestamp, you can make the other app open the file and see if the timestamp is different to the one it previously has saved. If it is different, you can perform the action you want with the new data. Do you also want to explicitly stop the data being posted to global clipboard?

Comment: The timestamp in my case wont work. I do not see as a solution to my problem.
Yes i need to explicitly stop data from being posted on global clipboard.

Comment: Another idea: implement a background listener in the second app that listens for a clip with a particular tag you set in the first app, using OnPrimaryClipChangeListener(), getPrimaryClipDescription() and getPrimaryClip(). When it's a match you can save it to a local variable in the second app. Users don't copy often enough for this small check to be heavy. Maybe you can reset the clipboard to a blank string using OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() in the first app; get its description and post another item to the clipboard with the same description but empty content.